# PHP - Deleting Cloudinary Derived Images

Tags: php, cloudinary

Using the following code I can delete an image based on the public id provided by cloudinary.

```
$imgID = 'lbxzgiajsarkyechqsz2';    
\Cloudinary\Uploader::destroy($imgID);
```

How would I go about deleting all derived images for that particular image in my cloudinary account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you delete an image then it automatically deletes all its derived images as well. If you want to delete only derived then pass the `keep_original` parameter to `true` and that will ensure only derivatives are deleted and original is kept as is.
For more information: https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/articles/202521072-How-to-delete-derived-resources-.